# How do sparsity and cardinality of features influence relevance in a random forest classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, random-forest

I am looking at relevance of my dataset features using the random forest implementation from Scikit learn.

I get some results which are making sense, but some others don't.

Some features have very sparse data. Only a few examples have 1 (about 1%), 99% have 0 as value. These features are extremely relevant in the classification but they are evaluated as unrelevant by the RF (close to 0% relevance).

Some features have a very high cardinality (large amount of different values) and I have the same issue as sparse features, they are considered irrelevant.

More generally, in what way sparsity and cardinality of features influence their relevance in a RF algorythm? how can it be addressed?